# Could not find the language 'cpp', did you forget to load/include a language module?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight.js

I want to use highlight.js in my website.But it doesn't work.
I use unpkg CDN and I import it like that:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.5.0/styles/rainbow.min.css">
<script src="//unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.5.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

and I also use `<script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>` in the end of my file.
I couldn't find anything wrong, but it still report a warning like that:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yept.png)

Can any one help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Wow, their documentation is terrible (and red for some reason). There's a tiny note on the [supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) doc that says _"our default minified web build includes only ~40 popular languages"_. I guess C++ isn't considered _popular_

Answer (score 2):

Include the language module.

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.5.1/languages/cpp.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use highlightjs with cdn in Vue has the same error,
I write it like this:

```
hljs.highlight(code, { language, ignoreIllegals })
```

then I change it to:

```
hljs.highlight(language, code, true)
```

It go work.